# & bitwise AND in bash

Tags: linux, bash, multiprocessing, synchronization, bitwise-operators

Is the bitwise AND (&) make the commands run as multiprocessing commands or does it do something different?
for example:
`python3.10 test1.py & python3.10 test2.py`
when I run this command it runs the programs as synchronized.
I hope you give me an explanation about bitwise operations in bash.
Thanks

Comment: In this context you are combining commands, not integers. So neither `&` nor `&&` is the bitwise AND (an operation that combines two integers). Are you asking about how to *chain* commands so that all chained commands *always* run (e.g. *"I want to run command1 AND command2"*?) If so, then picking a short-circuit AND operation like `&&` is not what you want. Instead, chain the commands with `;`, meaning you don't care about the exit status of the commands and always execute all of them.

Comment: Bitwise AND in bash is `&`, but that assumes an arithmetic context, for example: `echo $(( 1 & 0 ))`. What you need is _logical_ AND, which is `&&`.

Comment: Ok What will happen if I put more than two commands like:` python3.10 test1.py & python3.10 test2.py & python3.10 test3.py` @markp-fuso